# How to Handle Both Action Bar and Menu Button?

Tags: android

With the game I'm developing, I have an in-game menu the pops up when the menu button is pressed. However, I recently found out that the newer versions of Android don't have a Menu button, but instead an Action Bar.

To note, I'm not using an actual Android menu. All I'm doing is detecting that the Menu button was pressed, and then handling the event from within the game. Which means all I need is something that the user can press, and detect that it was pressed.

So my question is, how can I support both a menu button and the newer action bar? I would like my app to support API levels 7-current.

**UPDATE**

Okay, after reading [that article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29), I'd like to rephrase my question. It said that it "adds the action overflow button beside the system navigation." My manifest has android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13" but no overflow button appears on my emulator. The emulator is API 14 with skin WSVGA

Comment: Careful now, more and more device don't have the menu button anymore.

Comment: make use of the actionbar (with actionbar compact) then override onKeyDown and check for `keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post in the Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29) has a good discussion of the design transition from the old *Menu Button* to use of the new *Action Bar* and *Action Overflow* list.

It also includes some specific suggestions as to how to deal with your code when transitioning from pre-level 11 to the new Action Bar.  May be helpful to you but for your specific application you will need to decide if you want to display an action bar or not.  If not then you may want to add a button to your game interface that duplicates the functionality of the menu button on devices that have one.

Comment: Okay, after reading that article, I'd like to rephrase my question. It said that it "adds the action overflow button beside the system navigation." My manifest has `android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13"` but no overflow button appears on my emulator. The emulator is API 14 with skin WSVGA.

Comment: @JesseJ Yup, I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Where are you looking for the action overflow button?  On level "13" I believe it will appear on the right side of system navigation (at bottom of screen and not on the action bar).  Try targeting level "14". You should get it on the action bar.  Also, it sounds like you don't really want the action bar to appear at all.

Comment: @PaulP Yes, having it in the system navigation would be preferable. But, as I said, it doesn't appear there, despite doing what I was told to.

Comment: @JesseJ I know it's a bit late, but the reason you don't get the overflow button is that you're using an emulator. If you re-read the article it says "The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button **when running your app on a handset** with Android 4.0 or higher"

Comment: Huh. So basically I can't test it? Well that sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Android do have a Menu button (see quote below). I think you best option is to just hide the Action bar, and have your game use the menu button in the same way as on older Android versions.

Quoting from [Android 4.0 Compatibility Definition](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf)

> 7.2.3. Navigation keys
> The Home, Menu and Back functions are essential to the Android navigation paradigm.
>
> Device implementations MUST make these functions available to the user at all times when running applications.
>
> These functions MAY be implemented via dedicated physical buttons (such as mechanical or capacitive touch buttons), or MAY be
> implemented using dedicated software keys, gestures, touch panel, etc.Android 4.0 supports both implementations.

And:

> Device implementation MUST present a Menu key to applications when
> targetSdkVersion <= 10 and SHOULD NOT present a Menu key when the
> targetSdkVersion > 10.

Comment: My program looks for a menu button through `onKeyDown`. If there's no physical menu button, how do I make it work? How do I make a menu button appear if it doesn't have one?

Comment: Well if the soft menu button doesn't generate onKeyDown when you press on it, I don't know.Do you have a physical device that you can test this on?

Comment: My physical phone is Android 2.2, and I haven't seen a soft menu button 4.0